# file upload path into database in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Hi Every One,
            I'm trying to upload the file path in data base but it is redirecting same and file is not uploading can any one help me ..
This is My Controller.

```
<?php
if (!defined ('BASEPATH'))exit('no direct scripts allowed ');
class Main extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct ()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }



    function insert_quiz_data()
   {

    $this->load->library('form_validation'); //loading validation library

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('qtitle','quiz_title'); //setting rules for validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('qcategory1','quiz_category1');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('qcategory2','quiz_category2');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('qcategory3','quiz_category3');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('astatus','email');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'quiz_image_path', 'callback__do_upload'); //userfile is the upload file field name in form ,
    echo 'testing';

    if($this->form_validation->run()!=false)
    {


        //Get the info from the form
        $username   =   $this->input->post('qtitle');
        $password   =   $this->input->post('qcategory1');
        $passconf   =   $this->input->post('qcategory2');
        $date       =   $this->input->post('qcategory3');
        $email      =   $this->input->post('astatus');


        $temp=$this->upload->data();
        $image=$temp['file_name'];// to get image file name rom upload script , as it could be stored in the databae


        //load the model
        $this->load->model('quiz_mode');

        //execute the registration query
        $data = $this->quiz_mode->register_user($username,$password,$passconf,$date,$image,$email);

        //if $data == TRUE
        if($data)
        {
            echo "you have successfully made your registration";
             $this->load->view('logged_in_area');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "faillled";
        }
    }
    else{


        //You arrived here just in case the form fields are not correct
         $this->load->view('logged_in_area'); //loading reg form here
    }
}
    public function _do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';
        $field_name = 'userfile';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($field_name))
        {
              $this->form_validation->set_message('_do_upload', $this->upload->display_errors());
              return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            $image_data = $this->upload->data();
            $filename = $image_data['file_name'];
            $config = array
            (
              'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
              'new_image' => './uploads/thumbs/',
              'maintain_ratio' => false,
              'width' => 300,
              'height' => 200
            );
            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

My Model Class:

```
<?php
class File_model extends CI_Model
{
    function File_model()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function register_user($username,$password,$passconf,$date,$image,$email)
    {

          $data= array('username'=>$username,
        'password'=>$password,
        'passconf'=>$passconf,
        'date'=>$date,
        'image'=>$image,
        'email'=>$email
        );
       $res= $this->db->insert('register', $data); //register is my table name
        return $res;
        var_dump($res);
    }

}
?>
```

My View

```
<html>
<body>

<?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('index.php/main'); ?>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<table width="348" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><h2><strong>REGISTERATION AREA</strong></h2></td>
  </tr>
    <tr><?php  //echo validation_errors(); ?>
      <td width="97" height="40"><label for"username"> <strong>Username </strong></label></td>
      <td width="249"><input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for"password"> <strong>Password </strong></label></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for"confirm password"> <strong>Passconf</strong></label></td>
      <td><input type="password" name="passconf" id="passconf" value="<?php echo set_value('passconf'); ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for"date "><strong>Date</strong></label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Upload Picture</strong></td>
      <td><input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" id="userfile" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for"email"> <strong>Email</strong></label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="44">&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Register" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me .
Thanks.

Comment: you **really** shouldn't be doing the file uplaod via validation of an input field... thats the wrong way to go about it, should only upload the file ONCE all validation is correct, not when you check for validity of the file.

Comment: @Jakub Ok Can you give solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `_do_upload` function you do not pass the argument at the function, it can't use `$field_name`
Try to change it:

```
public function _do_upload($field_name)
```

There are different problem into your code.
First of all you load the view before the validation, in this way the view is always diplaied.
Try my following code (just the index function):

```
function index()
{


    $this->load->library('form_validation'); //loading validation library

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','username','Rquired'); //setting rules for validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','password','required|md5|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf','password confirmation','required|md5|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('datepicker','date','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'Image', 'callback__do_upload'); //userfile is the upload file field name in form ,


    if($this->form_validation->run()!=false)
    {


        //Get the info from the form
        $username   =   $this->input->post('username');
        $password   =   $this->input->post('password');
        $passconf   =   $this->input->post('passconf');
        $date       =   $this->input->post('datepicker');
        $email      =   $this->input->post('email');


        $temp=$this->upload->data();
        $image=$temp['file_name'];// to get image file name rom upload script , as it could be stored in the databae


        //load the model
        $this->load->model('file_model');

        //execute the registration query
        $data = $this->file_model->register_user($username,$password,$passconf,$date,$image,$email);

        //if $data == TRUE
        if($data)
        {               
            echo "you have successfully made your registration";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "faillled";
        }
    }
    else{
        //You arrived here just in case the form fields are not correct
         $this->load->view('register_form'); //loading reg form here
    }


}
```

Comment: Thaks,It's working but when i inserting this code to some other method it running                                                         else{
        
         $this->load->view('register_form'); 
    }
Can you help me .

Comment: it run the else part because the form in the page is not valid. If you need to use the code in the if stantment you have to delete the validation control

Comment: I deleted the validation control but not executing.Can you give solution.

Comment: I'm doing quiz sample .I'm trying to insert the form into database,with out file upload is ok for me but with file is not working .I Edited the my code above .Can you look the my Controller class  above Question

Comment: You try to load the quiz_model but your file is named File_module

Comment: try `$this->load->model('file_model','',TRUE);`

Comment: Actually IF Condition is not executing it is directly executing else part .

Comment: i think that the problem is with the file upload, try to delete the set_rules for it and try to execute the code and see what appens